# Is text commonly right-aligned in French?

Tags: typographie, formatage

I don't know French (just English, German, and learning Spanish).

I've noticed on some gutenberg.org French (and Italian) documents that the text is right-aligned. Is that common in French (and Italian), a quirk of the particular document, or...???

Comment: Which of the French gutemberg.org documents are right aligned ?

Comment: I don't recall at the moment; it could have been "Around the World in 80 Days" or "Robinson Crusoe" or "Gulliver's Travels" (the translations into French, in the latter two cases). It could be, though, that the doc I was pasting the text into was goofed up - although I didn't have them right-aligned (not something I would ever do). It happened in the Italian "Alice in Wonderland," too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In french, text is generally "justified" or left aligned.